# Can I queryparam a string used in a MySQL IN statement using ColdFusion?

Tags: mysql, string, coldfusion, query-string

I'm running MySQL 5.0.88 and Coldfusion8.

In a form, I'm grabbing a number of record ids from a table and send them to the server. The string will look like so:

```
 9900000002985,9900000003180,9900000003203,9900000003487,9900000003579
```

I'm then passing this into MySQL, initially like so:

```
SELECT bk.*
   FROM header AS bk
   WHERE 1
   AND bk.iln_kaeufer IN ( #passed_in_string# )
```

I have been trying for a while to use cfqueryparam like so:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" value="#passed_in_string#">
```

But this causes an error in ColdFusion. Whereas if I run the query directly in MySQL, it works. So it must be something with my cfqueryparam declaration.

I'm passing this form through AJAX from a remote location. So I don't get any error messages except for an AJAX commit error.

**Question**:
How do I secure the above string if I can't use `cfqueryparam`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the `list` and `separator` parameters of `cfqueryparam`.

```
SELECT bk.*
  FROM header AS bk
  WHERE 1
    AND bk.iln_kaeufer IN ( <cfqueryparam list="yes" separator="," cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" value="#passed_in_string#">)
```

Comment: I'd recommend moving list to the start of the tag so it's visible without scrolling.

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that existed. Cool!

Comment: You would know if you'd [read the docs for cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam). :P

Comment: Just a little heads-up: Please keep in mind that the "WHERE foo in (<params>)" approach can run into list length limitations, in case that list can grow quite large over the years (e.g., triple digits). In that case you'll need to break it up into blocks or even individual conditions to be on the safe side.