# Can I use MySQL "IN" with a list of strings in Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, string, select, coldfusion

I'm trying to feed a variables into an `MySQL` query from `Coldfusion`. My query currently includes:

```
<cfif Session.app_assign EQ "0">
    AND art.iln IN ( #Session.app_ilns# )
<cfelseif Session.app_assign EQ "1">
    AND art.marke IN ( "#Session.app_keys#" )
</cfif>
```

`Session.app_ilns` will be a list of numbers like so: 1111111111111,2222222222222.... which works fine. Howerver, `Session.app_keys` will be list of strings, like:

```
sample_1, sample_2, sample_3
```

which will produce an error in my script, because of

```
unknown column "sample_1, sample_2, sample_3" in where clause.
```

**Question**:
Is there a way to use MySQL `IN` with a list of string values or do I need to pre-loop over the variables to add quotation marks. Are there any other ways to get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a [php example](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2009/12/mysql-select-statement-where-something-exists-in-list.html) how to fix. Looking for a Coldfusion version to use in my MySQL query

Comment: Wow. Talk about [déjà vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722181/can-i-queryparam-a-string-used-in-a-mysql-in-statement-using-coldfusion/11722299).

Comment: @phantom42: ah.... I knew that problem sounded familiar... :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using a cfqueryparam (good practice anyhow) with `list="yes"`

See this [Ben Nadel blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1267-ColdFusion-CFQueryParam-Varchar-List-Puts-In-Single-Quotes-For-You.htm)

Code would look like:

```
AND art.marke IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#Session.app_keys#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes" />)
```

Comment: This possibility of seamlessly using lists in CF is one of its most excellent features.

Comment: yes, this is really awesome. Actually, I'm looking at a ton of code, which I can replace now...

Comment: Sadly this will not work if there are more than 2100 list items, or 2100 number of cfqueryparams in the whole Query.

Comment: Use `ListQualify()` function to apply characters at starting and ending of each list element.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. I can set `list="true"` in `cfqueryparam`. See [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1267-ColdFusion-CFQueryParam-Varchar-List-Puts-In-Single-Quotes-For-You.htm)